# Cannot create instance in contract because of overloaded constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I have two contracts, `TokenContract` and `DynamicContract`. The latter is created dynamically.

I want to call a function of `DynamicContract` from `TokenContract` (`receiveApproval`). According to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20750/error-calling-a-function-from-another-contract-member-not-found-or-not-visi), what I need to do is this:

```
function ApproveAndCall(address dynContAddress, uint value){
  DynamicContract dynamicContractInstance = DynamicContract(dynContAddress);
  dynamicContractInstance.foo();

  return true;
}
```

I have `import "./DynamicContract.sol";` at the beginning of my TokenContract.

The thing is, I already have a constructor for `DynamicContract` and it takes a bunch of parameters. So I get a compilation error stating I don't have the right parameters.

I also tried using simply `DynamicContract(dynContAddress).foo()` but I get `Member "foo" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address`

EDIT:
Maybe I should use `function ApproveAndCall(DynamicContract dynContAddress, ...){}` instead of `function ApproveAndCall(address dynContAddress, ...)` if I want to use `dynContAddress.foo(){}`? What's the difference?

---

<sub>I think the problem might come from the fact that both contract call functions of the other, so both have `import "./OtherContract.sol"`. Since one has to compile before the other there might be a problem (Solidity isn't as flexible as some other languages).</sub>

<sub>Could it be the problem? Then how could I solve it? (I don't think the contract is over complicated, I just want to pay for functions in token and transfer them to the address they belong to).</sub>

**EDIT 2**:
Actually I don't think that's the problem because when running `truffle compile`, I get `Compiling .\contracts\DynamicContract.sol...`and `Compiling .\contracts\Factory.sol...` before `Compiling .\contracts\Token.sol...` that gives the error. (`member not found or not visible` ...)

Comment: is foo defined as public? If is external it may not work

Comment: @mirg Yes, I simplified it for the example but all the functions I call externally are public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To create a new contract from within another contract:

#### a. If ether needs to be supplied upon construction:

```
DynamicContract dynamicContractInstance = 
     (new DynamicContract).value(<ether to send>)(<param1>, <param2>, ...);
```

#### b. If ether does not need to be supplied upon construction:

```
DynamicContract dynamicContractInstance = 
     new DynamicContract(<param1>, <param2>, ...);
```

Then, the function can be called:

```
dynamicContractInstance.foo();
```

### If the address of the "dynamic" contract has already been obtained:

the function can be called:

```
dynContAddress.foo();
```

Comment: I don't know if it's clear but the contract is already created, I only want to make an instance by using the address (that I already have)

Comment: Is "the address (that I already have)" = dynContAddress?  If so, there is no need to recreate or cast the contract, it's possible to use

    dynContAddress.foo(); 

to call the function.

Comment: Yes it is, but as I said in the last part of my question, `addressThatIAlreadyHave.foo()` doesn't work, I get "member not found or not accessible" (even though it's public), I don't know why I, have I missed something?

Comment: This gist contains the code that I used to validate the answer: https://gist.github.com/fidsteve/87fdd61996dfa04085161aecbc363690

Comment: I think I know the problem. In my `foo()` function, there is `tokenContract.transferFrom` so dynContract has to `import "./TokenContract.sol"`. But TokenContract also needs to `import "./DynamicContract"`to call `dynContAddress.foo()`. So maybe one has to compile first and it doesn't have the other one compiled already. Could that be it? How do I solve this?

Comment: Maybe it's the token function definition? I used to have something like `function approveAndCall (address dynContAddr, uint arg1){...}`, I switched to `function approveAndCall ( DynContract dynContAddr, uint arg1){...}`. Is it better? Can I call that with an address?